# Check multiple textareas if empty

Tags: html, jsp

I have multiple textareas and I'm trying to check if all of them were empty, then a message should be prompted to the user asking him to check his entries and have at least one text area filled.

```js
function checkEvent() {
  console.log("infunc");
  if (document.getElementById('events_yes').checked) {
    document.getElementById('if_events_yes').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('if_events_yes').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function checkText() {
  var content = document.getElementsByName("firewall").value.trim() + document.getElementsByName("ids").value.trim() +
    document.getElementsByName("proxy").value.trim() + document.getElementsByName("dpi").value.trim() +
    document.getElementsByName("net_malware").value.trim() + document.getElementsByName("av").value.trim() +
    document.getElementsByName("forensics").value.trim() + document.getElementsByName("tripwire").value.trim() +
    document.getElementsByName("memdumps").value.trim() + document.getElementsByName("email_logs").value.trim();
  alert(content.length);

}
```

```html
<form action="ResponseDB" method="post">
  <input name="tipid" value="<% out.println(tipid);%>" hidden="">Any events to report?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="events" onclick="javascript:checkEvent();" id="events_yes" value="yes">Yes
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="events" onclick="javascript:checkEvent();" id="events_no" value="no" checked>No
  <br>

  <div id="if_events_yes" hidden>
    <br>
    <br>Firewall:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="firewall" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>IDS/IPS:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="ids" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Web Content Filtering/Proxy:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="proxy" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Deep packet inspection:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="dpi" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Network malware protection devices (FireEye, Damballa, etc.):
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="net_malware" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Anti-virus software:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="av" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Forensics Tools:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="forensics" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Tripwire:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="tripwire" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Memory Dumps:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="memdumps" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>Email logs:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="email_logs" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:checkText();" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong ? When I click submit nothing happens, the form will be submitted even if it was empty

Comment: You can't have multiple ids, and also - you should prevent default behavior on submit, if empty textarea is found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `required` attribute for this instead of javascript. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) for it's use, and here's an example:

```css
form *{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form action="ResponseDB" method="post">
  <textarea required></textarea>
  <textarea required></textarea>
  <textarea required></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

Now that I understand the question more, here's my updated answer:

```js
function checkEvent() {
  console.log("infunc");
  if (document.getElementById('events_yes').checked) {
    document.getElementById('if_events_yes').style.display = "table-caption";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('if_events_yes').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function checkText() {
var childDivs = document.getElementById('if_events_yes').getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var content = 0;
for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
{
 content += childDivs[i].value.length;
}
  alert(content);

}
```

```html
<form action="ResponseDB" method="post">
  <input name="tipid" value="<% out.println(tipid);%>" hidden="">Any events to report?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="events" onclick="javascript:checkEvent();" id="events_yes" value="yes">Yes
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="events" onclick="javascript:checkEvent();" id="events_no" value="no" checked>No
  <br>

  <div id="if_events_yes" hidden>
    Firewall: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="firewall" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    IDS/IPS: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="ids" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Web Content Filtering/Proxy: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="proxy" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Deep packet inspection: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="dpi" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Network malware protection devices (FireEye, Damballa, etc.): <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="net_malware" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Anti-virus software: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="av" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Forensics Tools: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="forensics" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Tripwire: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="tripwire" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Memory Dumps: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="memdumps" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
    Email logs: <textarea rows="5" cols="80" type="text" name="email_logs" id="if_events_yes"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="checkText();" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to have at least one textarea filled not all of them, any similar way?

Comment: But in the question you said "I'm trying to check if all of them were empty", if you've had a change of heart that's fine, please edit your question though to clarify ;) I cannot think of a way of doing that. Although tbh, I would allow the user to add as many reports as possible, and remove any unneeded ones. Eg when they click 'Yes', add one textarea and a dropdown to select the type of error, and a button to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. 
I only need the user to have at least one entry. If none a message should be prompted.

Comment: @user4071915 I have updated my answer, is this what you want? :)